# how to mock a service method inside a controller for unit testing in grails using JUnit and when to use mockController

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit

Help me understand how to mock a service method inside a controller for unit testing in grails using JUnit

I was trying to write a unit test case for my controller "add".

```
void testAdd_UT_03(){

......declaring and assigning prerequisites

   controller.add() // This is the controller i want to unit test

.... asserting 

  }
```

//Controller
     def add{

```
  def a =someService.method()

  }
```

Inside controller, some service methods are getting called which in turn is using HQL statements. Since i could not find a way to deal with HQL statements in unit testing, i want to mock the service method itself. ( i want the service method to return the predefined output).
Could someone please explain how to achieve this?

Could you also explain when to use mockController? what we really achieve by mocking something? ( i dint get the real picture as i am entirely new to this)

Thanks in advance,
BK

Comment: Just to clarify, i need to override the service method when the call is made from the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the following code in the setUp method of your test to mock the service method and when you call the method "add" method on your controller it will call the mocked service method.

```
def predifinedOutput
void setUp(){
    def mockControl = mockFor(YourService)
      //params are the parameters passed to the service method
      mockControl.demand.yourServiceMethod(0..10) { params-> 
      predifnedOutput = "predifinedOutput"          
      return "predefined output"
    }


    controller.yourService = mockControl.createMock()
}
```

Comment: when i tried, i am getting the below error " junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No more calls to 'generatePassword' expected at this point. End of demands."

Comment: public String generateUserName(String username) {
  log.debug("Enter(Method) - generateUserName()")
  String tempUserName = null;
  Sql db = new Sql(dataSource)..................................//some logic.....  }

Comment: the range 0..10 defines the number of times you expect the method to be called. the asserion error is thrown because the method is being called more than 10 times. (change 10 to the number times you expect the method to be called)